# Confused about how to make stomp calls with Spring-websockets

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

From 21.4.2 of the Spring documentation of WebSockets there is this explanation:

> Or if connecting via WebSocket (without SockJS):
>
> `var socket = new WebSocket("/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio");`
>
> `var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);`
>
> `stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) { }`

I don't understand how we make a WebSocket connection without the usual `ws://hostname:port/appName/...`

Also, I cannot find any examples for connecting via a Java client using the Spring-websocket code.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that there must be some special case where this works:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio");
```

I ended up making the connection by using the path:

```
ws://localhost:8080/MyWebAppName/portfolio
```

Portfolio is the name of my stomp endpoint. I guess in this context of the documentation the hostname and port doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: did you find any java client for this